# proper way to call a shell file from VBA written in excel 2010

Tags: vba, perl, shell

I can call a `perl` script from `VBA` doing:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "c:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl"
```

However, is it possible to call a .sh file instead?  The .sh is called Run.sh and within it is a reference to the `perl` script.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. And since it appears that you have Cygwin installed, you already have a shell script interpreter on your system:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /home/cmccabe/Run.sh"
```

Comment: I am getting a windows can not find `"c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /home/cmccabe/Run.sh"` maybe it needs the full path `"c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe c:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\Run.sh'`, but then won't it try to read the full path as is and throw the same error? Thank you :).